# Bluetooth speaker automatically sets audio profile off

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, a2dp

When my laptop (Dell Latitude E7240 with Ubuntu 18.04) is connected to my bluetooth speaker (JBL Clip 3) the audio profile of this one goes automatically to "Off" and not to "A2DP" as I would like. The speaker is found by the computer automatically, but I would like to connect it automatically to the A2DP audio profile, as now I always have to open the bluetooth devices window and change it manually.

I've tried to modify the file /etc/bluetooth/main.conf adding the lines

```
AutoConnect=true
Disable=Headset
MultiProfile = multiple
```

as suggested by several threads online, but it didn't work.
Is there a way maybe to disable the "Off" profile instead of "Headset", since this is my problem?